# How can I make a "Find Form" for RichTextBox while keeping SelectionColor? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am making a Notepad with Syntax highlighting.

I made the Syntax-Highlighting work, but now I need help :D

I need a "Find Form" that works with this code:

```
            // getting keywords/functions
            string keywords = @"\b(abstract|as|base|break|case|catch|checked|continue|default|delegate|do|else|event|explicit|extern|false|finally|fixed|for|foreach|goto|if|implicit|in|interface|internal|is|lock|namespace|new|null|object|operator|out|override|params|private|protected|public|readonly|ref|return|sealed|sizeof|stackalloc|switch|this|throw|true|try|typeof|unchecked|unsafe|using|virtual|volatile|while)\b";
            MatchCollection keywordMatches = Regex.Matches(codeRichTextBox.Text, keywords);

            string purplewords = @"\b(bool|byte|char|class|const|decimal|double|enum|float|int|long|sbyte|short|static|string|struct|uint|ulong|ushort|static|void)\b";
            MatchCollection purplewordsMatches = Regex.Matches(codeRichTextBox.Text, purplewords);

            // getting types/classes from the text 
            string types = @"\b(Console)\b";
            MatchCollection typeMatches = Regex.Matches(codeRichTextBox.Text, types);

            // getting comments (inline or multiline)
            string comments = @"(\/\/.+?$|\/\*.+?\*\/)";
            MatchCollection commentMatches = Regex.Matches(codeRichTextBox.Text, comments, RegexOptions.Multiline);

            // getting strings
            string strings = "\".+?\"";
            MatchCollection stringMatches = Regex.Matches(codeRichTextBox.Text, strings);

            // saving the original caret position + forecolor
            int originalIndex = codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart;
            int originalLength = codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength;
            Color originalColor = Color.Black;

            // MANDATORY - focuses a label before highlighting (avoids blinking)
            menuStrip1.Focus();

            // removes any previous highlighting (so modified words won't remain highlighted)
            codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = 0;
            codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = codeRichTextBox.Text.Length;
            codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = originalColor;

            // scanning...
            foreach (Match m in keywordMatches)
            {
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
            }

            foreach (Match m in purplewordsMatches)
            {
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Purple;
            }

            foreach (Match m in typeMatches)
            {
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.DarkCyan;
            }

            foreach (Match m in commentMatches)
            {
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
            }

            foreach (Match m in stringMatches)
            {
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Brown;
            }

            // restoring the original colors, for further writing
            codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = originalIndex;
            codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = originalLength;
            codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = originalColor;

            // giving back the focus
            codeRichTextBox.Focus();
```

- That is **Full** C# highlighting. I need it to work with a "Find Form", like in Notepad++ :)

My current "Find Form" code:

```
    public static void Find(RichTextBox rtb, String word, Color color)
    {
        rtb.SelectionStart = 0;
        rtb.SelectionLength = rtb.TextLength;
        rtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
        if (word == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        int s_start = rtb.SelectionStart, startIndex = 0, index;
        while ((index = rtb.Text.IndexOf(word, startIndex)) != -1)
        {
            rtb.Select(index, word.Length);
            rtb.SelectionBackColor = color;
            startIndex = index + word.Length;
        }
    }
```

It works fine(**Without Syntax**), but if I have Syntax switched ***ON***, it glitches out :(

I can provide more info if needed :)

P.S: I know I made a question for a "Find Form" before, but this is a different type of question :)

Comment: Might be worth looking at Scintilla which is a package used for text editors (it is the one used by notepad++).  It would be far easier than writting it all from scratch (unless this is a technical exercise).  It has built in lexers and you can define your own.  It doesn't have much overhead and has good documentation.  The C# package is scintilla.net (https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET).  You can install it through NuGet.

Comment: I'll give it a try, then come back to you :)

Comment: Thomas, how would I use it? I downloaded it from Nuget, but I can't find a way to actually use it. Is there a ToolBox item? Or a command?

Comment: from their documentation: https://www.scintilla.org/SciTry.vb

Comment: Are you making a code editor?

Comment: Yes, I am, Democrats :)

Comment: The documentation isn't helping -- I'm doing C# :(

Comment: vb to c# converters are very good: http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you decide to go with Scintilla.NET then you want to install the nuget package direct from visual studio (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio).  You can then create a new one by doing `using ScintillaNET;` and `new Scintilla()`.

I have used it in my codebase (C#) here https://github.com/HicServices/RDMP/blob/f85f1c7f03bc0cdcbabe7ef83d12fa1f4d25bdae/Reusable/ReusableUIComponents/ScintillaHelper/ScintillaTextEditorFactory.cs

Heres an excerpt

```
            var toReturn =  new Scintilla();
            toReturn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            toReturn.HScrollBar = true;
            toReturn.VScrollBar = true;

            if (lineNumbers)
                toReturn.Margins[0].Width = 40; //allows display of line numbers
            else
                foreach (var margin in toReturn.Margins)
                    margin.Width = 0;

            toReturn.ClearCmdKey(Keys.Control | Keys.S); //prevent Ctrl+S displaying ascii code
            toReturn.ClearCmdKey(Keys.Control | Keys.R); //prevent Ctrl+R displaying ascii code
            toReturn.ClearCmdKey(Keys.Control | Keys.W); //prevent Ctrl+W displaying ascii code
```

Once it is showing you can view the documentation on automatic code highlighting here https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/wiki/Custom-Syntax-Highlighting

Comment: But, Thomas N, how would I install the latest version? I am on Visual Studio 2013, because 2019 is freezing like crazy.

Comment: Thomas, what is 'lineNumbers"? I need to know!! Please..? :)

Comment: Should "toReturn" appear in the toolbox? it isn't for me

Comment: Hey line numbers is a local variable, true to show line numbers.  Just delete the else and the if the only bit you need is `toReturn.Margins[0].Width = 40`.  `toReturn` is the scintilla control you can add it to your form by doing `myform.Controls.Add(toReturn)`

Comment: I usually add a Panel to my form and then call a method after `InitializeComponent` in the form constructor to add the Scintilla control into the panel.  I don't think you can use the designer/toolbox with Scintilla.NET.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know how to install nuget packages on visual studio 2013 :( but Google should provide the answer to that

Comment: They should have made `new Scintilla();` a control in the `ToolBox` that would work better :)